# How to produce the following three dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a cube of size `N * N * N`, say `N=8`. Each dimension of the cube is discretised to 1, so that I have labelled points `(0,0,0), (0,0,1)..(N,N,N)`. At each labelled points, I would like to assign a random value, and thus produce an array which stores value at each vertex. For example `val[0,0,0]=1, val[0,0,1]=1.2 val[0,1,0]=1.3`, ...

How do I write a python code to acheive this?

Comment: Can you pleas update your question with the code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply generate lists of lists. While not in any way efficient, it would allow you to access your cube like `val[0][0][0]`.

```
arr = [[[] for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]

arr[0][0].append(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this:

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
val = np.empty((n, n, n)) # Create an 3d array full of 0's
val[0,0,0] = 11
val[0,0,1] = 33 
print(val[0, 0])
array([ 11.,  33.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

For large matrices, look into using `numpy`.  This is the problem that it's designed to solve